# HTML is backwards & Width messes everything up

Tags: html, css

I am putting text over an image. Which I did correctly I think. But when i look at it through chrome, It shows the Navigation backwards.

http://gyazo.com/464d7131759cfdb6b1d64ed52bc127ef

This is the code i have

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
        <li>Forum</li>
        <li>Donate</li>
        <li>Vote</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  display:inline-block;
  background: url('Img/navigation.png') no-repeat center;
}

nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:10px 8px 10px 8px;
    float: right;
    width: 1600px
}

nav li{
    list-style:none;
    padding:15px 10px 15px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: green;
    float: right;
}

nav a, nav a:visited{
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    float: right;
}
```

Then my second problem is when i try to increase the width so it fits over the whole page, it moves everything and takes the text off of the background.

http://gyazo.com/3a022e7dc613b3afb772068ac3764ca1

```
nav ul{
list-style:none;
padding:10px 8px 10px 8px;
    float: right;
    width: 1600px
}
```

Comment: remove float: right from .nav?

Comment: You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: your link is wrapped incorrectly: `<a href="index.html"><li>Homepage</li></a>` should be `<li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>`

Comment: I fixed that HTML Error. And i took off the float, But it only bumped up the Navigation part. This is the Completed Version we are trying to make http://gyazo.com/11693372a365d6cee5349e8cb065e56c
This is what it looks like after the updates you told me to do.
http://gyazo.com/3a022e7dc613b3afb772068ac3764ca1

Comment: Your `li` are floating right

Comment: @Huangism They are supposed to be floated right. Look at the completed project we made in Photoshop.

Comment: @Rangerman201 where is it? the first link just spins and shows nothing for me. By float right do you mean the `ul` should be right aligned or the `li` themselves? because if the `li` is floated right AND you think the nav items are backwards, then there is only one logic conclusion, rearrange your `li` so they appear correctly on the page

Comment: @Huangism Here is another link for you. http://imgur.com/yoiOwg6

Comment: @Rangerman201 I have created a simple example for you to see what happens when you float right http://jsfiddle.net/dJ4a8/

Comment: @Rangerman201 by the look of the image your li should not be floating and the ul or nav should be used for positioning

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this

http://jsfiddle.net/dJ4a8/1/

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Remove all the floats you have and add the `text-align` on the `ul`. There are other ways to achieve what you want, this is just one of them.

When you float the `li` right, it will reverse the appears from the order in the html which is what you are seeing

Comment: Almost. Still on the left side of the page. And the Image doesnt go across the page :/

Comment: The code I have works on a basic level as shown in the fiddle. As to your site, I have no idea what other components you have that might affect this.